# Installing CUDA-8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Nvidia GeForce 845m

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda

After having installed nvidia driver 367 by typing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367 -y
```

and disabled Secure Boot in UEFI (BIOS) settings, I'm trying to install properly nvidia-cuda 8.0.

These were my steps (following [this guide](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/NVIDIA-CUDA-with-Ubuntu-16-04-beta-on-a-laptop-if-you-just-cannot-wait-775/)):

1. from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads I downloaded cuda_8.0.44_linux.run
2. `sudo mkdir /usr/local/cuda-8.0`
3. `sudo ./cuda_8.0.44_linux.run --override`
4. in /etc/profile.d/cuda.sh: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin`
5. in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda.conf: `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`
6. `sudo ldconfig`
7. Force cuda to work with gcc 5, commenting line 119 out in usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h: `//#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!`
8. `rsync -av /usr/local/cuda/samples` in my cuda_samples/
9. `sudo GLPATH=/usr/lib make`

However, when i type:

```
./nbody -benchmark -numbodies=256000
```

in samples/bin/x86_64/linux/release, I get this message:

***Error: only 0 Devices available, 1 requested.  Exiting.***

Any help?

Comment: Apparently, CUDA works by installing its own version of NVIDIA driver (therefore, downgrading from nvidia-367.57). However, after rebooting I got stuck into the login loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially solved this way:

1. `sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-*`
2. `sudo service lightdm stop`
3. download nvidia driver *NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.57.run* from the website
4. `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.57.run --no-opengl-files`
5. `sudo ./cuda_8.0.44_linux.run` (you should not install its own nvidia-driver 367.48, as you have 367.57 already installed)
6. in */usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/host_config.h*, comment this line out: `#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!`
7. `mkdir cuda_samples`
8. `rsync -av /usr/local/cuda/samples .`
9. `GLPATH=/usr/lib make`
10. `reboot`

And you get your cuda-8.0 enabled!

**CAVEAT: As you got nvidia driver from the website, nvidia-settings doesn't work.** I am trying now to figure out how to make nvidia-settings properly work.